# Why is portrait mode restriction not working on iPad (but working on iPhone)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

[image: screenshot]

As you can see from the deployment info, the universal app is set to support Portrait mode only, this works very well on iPhone. My app is always in portrait mode on iPhones.

However, on iPad, if you rotate it to Landscape modes, the layout of the app changes along with the rotation, and it looks like a mess. Also, it is impossible for my UX to adjust to it, since the UI is designed for portrait only.

Is there a way to restrict iPad to the portrait orientation?